# Problems with migrating a system with JBoss EAP 6.3 Standalone + Apache for Wildfly 15 Domain + Apache with modcluster

Tags: java, apache, jboss, wildfly, mod-cluster

I'm in the process of migrating a system that uses JBoss EAP 6.3 Standalone + Apache to an environment that uses Wildfly 15 + Apache with modcluster, and I'm having some difficulties to make the system work correctly in this new scenario.

After all settings have been made, I performed the deployment of this [.war](https://github.com/efsavage/hello-world-war) file for testing and I was able to access the Hello Wolrd page normally, but once I've deployed my application, whenever I try to access it through the browser, the page goes into an infinite loop of requests displaying a 500 error. It is important to say that my application is evidently more complex, since it uses sessions, cookies, redirection of requests, among other things, 
and I believe the configuration I did in apache for this new scenario is incorrect, still missing some adjustments.

Here is the Apache configuration for the old scenario using JBoss EAP 6.3 Standalone, note that it's pretty simple:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    TimeOut 1800
    ServerName test.app.net.br
    ProxyPass /server-status !
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/app/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/app/
    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /
    <Location /server-status>
        SetHandler server-status
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 192.168.0.0/23
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

And here's the configuration I tried to do in Apache modecluster to work with Wildfly 15:

```
<IfModule manager_module>
    Listen 192.168.8.91:8080
    ManagerBalancerName appcluster
    <VirtualHost 192.168.8.91:8080>
        <Directory />
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        KeepAliveTimeout 60
        MaxKeepAliveRequests 0

        ProxyPass / balancer://appcluster
        ProxyPassReverse / balancer://appcluster
        ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /

        AdvertiseFrequency 5
        EnableMCPMReceive On
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

So any hint or help that helps me understand what is missing to make my system work in this new scenario is welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a lot of research, I was able to figure out what the problem...
The problem was in the incompatibility with the version of the Wildfly that I used along with the application, and since I did not have much time to figure out what I was missing, I decided to use an older version of JBoss, the EAP 6.4.